# Solving (simple?) math exercise (about ship and raft)

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

> There was a race between ship and a raft.
>
> Ship's own speed = `v`.
>   Raft's own speed = 0, but when going down stream it moves at speed = `p`. (flow of the river)
>
> Rules of the race:
>   first go downstream 20km, then turn around and come back to the starting point.
>   (total 40km)
>
> Ship completed full route (forth and back) in 7h.
>   Raft met ship, at 12km mark from the start. (ship already had turned around)
>
> What is the speed of the ship and the river flow? (v=?;p=?)

I got this from school book.
So my assumption was that solution should be quite straightforward.

But in my approach I get some cubic equation at one point, which seems too complicated compared to all other exercises in same book.

Is there some trivial solution that I don't see? What's the simplest way to approach it?

---

My naive approach.

Here is the equation system that I start with.

$
\begin{cases}
20/(v+p) + 20/(v-p) = 7 \\
20/(v+p) +  8/(v-p) = 12/p
\end{cases}
$

Express `v` through `p` (or vice versa) and then use it in other equation.

1st equation 'simplifies' to $40v - 7v^2 +7p^2=0$.

Solve it for `v`, and then put that into the 2nd equation.

But expression of `v` it self is non-trivial and putting that into 2nd equation creates some even more complicated thing.

BTW. the answer is:

> v=7, p=3

EDIT:
ok seems that simple path is just starting with 2nd equation..
(thanks @james15c; now I feel silly :) )

2nd equation simplifies to $28vp - 12v^2 = 0$,
which can be rewritten to $v (28p - 12v) = 0$
We can ignore solution $v=0$, so it leaves $28p - 12v = 0$,
in other words $v = 7p/3$

Make substitution into 1st equation $40(7p/3) - 7(7p/3)^2 +7p^2=0$
which simplifies to $p^2 - 3p=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good. I would recommend that next you solve the second equation to simplify it. Not just put terms in. The terms should be a lot simpler and a much nicer substitution. I would start off by making the two fractions one, then multiply over the denominator... you do the rest.